# _TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>')

Tags: json, laravel, flutter, api

i'm trying to create an auth user register with laravel. Then I got this kind of problem with my json. I created a dynamic map call to set the received json.

[image]

```
createAccount() async{
    bool emailValid = RegExp(
      r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+"
    ).hasMatch(_email);
    if(emailValid){
      http.Response response = await AuthService.register(
        _name, _email, _password
      );
      var encodeFirst = jsonEncode(response.body);
      Map responseMap = jsonDecode(encodeFirst);
      if(response.statusCode ==200){
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => HomePage()));
      } else{
        errorSnackBar(context, responseMap.values.first[0]);
      }
    } else {
      errorSnackBar(context, 'email not valied');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you share your JSON response here?

Comment: Also, error log from the consol if possible.

Comment: Can you try with removing `var encodeFirst = jsonEncode(response.body);` and just using `Map responseMap =jsonEncode(response.body);`

Comment: W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 2526): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
2
D/InputConnectionAdaptor( 2526): The input method toggled cursor monitoring on
I/TextInputPlugin( 2526): Composing region changed by the framework. Restarting the input method.
2
D/InputConnectionAdaptor( 2526): The input method toggled cursor monitoring on
I/flutter ( 2526): Instance of 'Response'

this is from debug console.

Comment: `$rules = [
    'email' => 'required',
    'password' => 'required|string',
];
$req->validate($rules);
$user = User::where('email',$req->email)->first();

if($user && Hash::check($req->password, $user->password)){
    $token = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token')->plainTextToken;
    $response = ['user' => $user, 'token'=>$token];
    return response()->json($response, 200);
}
$response = ['message' => 'incorecct email or password'];
return response()->json($response, 400);`

this is my json response

Comment: if using `Map responseMap =jsonEncode(response.body);` this error will appear " String jsonEncode(Object? object, {Object? Function(Object?)? toEncodable})"